# Can not add a child and parent object at same time

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a CoreData-backed app which represents some kind of folders-hierachy.

So a Folder can have a subfolders.

Therefore `NSManagedObject` the relationships *parent* and *children*

The Serverside only supports a two-level-hierachy at the moment.
Mainfolder -> Subfolder.

But to prepared for the future, the CoreData-Model is designed to support endless amount of levels.

so the relationship is

```
parent <------>> children
```

The folder also has an attribute `name`

So, the format for `NSPredicate` has `"parent != nil"` and the `NSFetchedResultsController` has `parent.name` as `sectionNameKeyPath`

Now as FRC will not contain empty sections (in this context: Folder without a childfolder). I create a default childfolder (this folder is used internally … so I will not mess up users hierachy).

So again I do the following if a user creates a new mainfolder:

```
Folder * mainFolder = [self createNewFolderWithName:userSetName];
Folder * systemChildSubfolder = [self createNewFolderWithName:SYSTEM_SUBFOLDER_NAME];

[mainFolder addChildFolderObject:systemChildSubfolder];

[self saveContext];
```

This works fine but when the delegate methods of FRC kick in, I'll get this error:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 0 into section 3, but there are only 0 rows in section 3 after the update with userInfo (null)
```

So it seems, the FRC stumbles over the new section and the inserted row. 
But I have not found away get around this. Even if I create and add the `systemChildSubfolder` after the mainFolder has been created AND saved … I still get that error.
It seems that FRC still returns the old number of sections and tries to add the new row in the wrong section?

So anyone could explain me how to get FRC work as I expect:
First add the section and then add the row?

FRC-Delegates:

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

        [[self folderTableView] beginUpdates];
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [[self folderTableView] insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            return;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [[self folderTableView] deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            return;
        default:
            return;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:

            [[self folderTableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]
                                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [[self folderTableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        {

                UITableViewCell * tableViewCell = [[self tableView] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
                Folder * folder = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                [self configureTableViewCell:tableViewCell withFolder:folder];

        }
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:

            [[self folderTableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]
                                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            [[self folderTableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


            break;
    }

}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
   [[self folderTableView] endUpdates];
}
```

**Short update:**

My suspicion is that the FRC does not updates for the new parent although it has a childfolder.

But the update for the new child has the correct IndexPath (if it's parent is in the FRC) but it does not fit with what is inside stored in the FRC.

Comment: Why isn't it `"parent == nil"` if you want to support arbitrary depth and allow the user to drill down. You'r current interface won't show hierarchy, it will be a really big sectioned list... It would also avoid the folders you're creating for management

Comment: The rows are the subfolders and they do have a parent.
The Parentfolders will be represented in the sections. 
That all works fine and correct, the problem lies somewhere in the FRC and it's delegate

Comment: but when you add a 3rd depth of folders they will also appear as rows, so your level 2 rows will then also be sections with more rows - is that really what you / users want ?

Comment: also, you don't show the delegate implementation, or the table delegate where the FRC is used, or list the change that is received before the crash

Comment: You are right … but currently we have only 2 levels and therefore it's ok to have parent !=nil

Comment: your question says `But to prepared for the future, the CoreData-Model is designed to support endless amount of levels` and this is a significant issue for that and for how you deal with data management

Comment: You are right … but my problem is not in stuff that has not implemented on the server side yet.

Comment: You need to show your code and a log of the FRC reported changes, somewhere you call insert on the row before the section row count has been updated

Comment: FRC-Delegates added to OP

Comment: And when you debug what order are the FRC updates called in?

Comment: `2015-11-16 15:15:26.405 Folded[52944:5283782] -[MSCFolderTableViewController controllerWillChangeContent:]
2015-11-16 15:15:26.405 Folded[52944:5283782] -[MSCFolderTableViewController controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert
2015-11-16 15:15:26.406 Folded[52944:5283782] -[MSCFolderTableViewController controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert
2015-11-16 15:15:26.406 Folded[52944:5283782] -[MSCFolderTableViewController controllerDidChangeContent:`

This is the order of the calls … seems fine to me

Answer (score 0):

#### Two levels

As has been pointed out in the comments, your setup is not feasible for more than two levels. Because you only want to deal with parent and child, I recommend the following simple solution:

Create two entities, `MainFolder` and `SubFolder`. You can have an abstract parent entity of kind `Folder` if you like, but that is not strictly necessary.

```
MainFolder (subFolders) <------>> (mainFolder) SubFolder
```

Fetch the `SubFolders` and use `mainFolder` as the `sectionNameKeyPath.

That's it, could not be simpler.

---

#### Infinite Levels

If you want to implement a potentially infinite hierarchy, you should perhaps ask a new question after you have gotten this setup to work.

Hint: You would have only one kind of entity, `Folder`, which would also have an attribute `level`. When creating folders and setting the `parent` you would check the `level` and set the own `level` as the parent's level plus one. The relationships up and down the hierarchy would be *reflexive*, that is, refer to the same `Folder` entity.

In the FRC you would fetch the parents (via a predicate based on level) without a `sectionNameKeyPath`, use `objectAtIndexPath` as for the section and populate the rows below the sections according to `folder.children` in the corresponding table view `datasource` methods (`numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).

Comment: My CoreData-Model is designed for infinite levels. But the TableView is currently not able to or to be more specific it treats any folder below level 1 equal.
Again, that is not the problem!

To explain it again:
The problem is that the FRC does not contains any new folder at level 1 (which is represented in the section) even if it comes with at least one subfolder.
It's standard FRC behaviour that sections without any objects will be ignored but this new section comes with an object.
Currently it seems, that the FRC does not handle (insert) the new section but tries to insert the row object.

Comment: I understand. My answer contains the solution.

Comment: I also tried that approach … but it had some other drawbacks.
I did some extensive debugging yesterday and it's strange, the FRC is updated and after adding a new parent plus default child it has the section. but the tableview controller did not update … even more strange:
After the new folders have been created and appear in the FRC I do a `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` but it has absolute no effect.
Event more, I did a `reloadData` (which should be totally avoided if FRC is used) … but even the `reloadData` does not do any refresh for the tableView.